# How can I modify my my RestKit managed object before it is saved via Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I have RestKit setup nicely with a Core Data managed object backing but I have some fields which are not present on the server, only in the local model class.

How can I set these fields before the object is persisted. Is there something like a 'willSave' delegate method I can implement?

Thanks

Comment: The object isn't persisted (aka inserted into the persistent store via the managed object context) until you save. Why can't you just set your properties prior to saving?

Comment: Persisting is handled automatically by the RKManagedObjectStore backed RKObjectManager when I call loadObjectsAtResourcePath. I was looking for a way to intercept the save before it happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish, but you can override `willSave` in NSManagedObject. The docs give a good explanation of what it does.

Comment: I think this is the simplest way to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: how did this solution interact with cached objects?  were you able to only modify values the first time you received a new object, and not when the cached value was found?

Comment: @deepwinter I don't know RestKit well, but you could take a look at `-awakeFromFetch` (and `-awakeFromInsert`, for that matter). They give you opportunities to update the object at other times. If that doesn't solve your problem, please go ahead and post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify the incoming data before you save it, you should consider [willMapData](http://restkit.org/api/0.10.0/Protocols/RKObjectLoaderDelegate.html#//api/name/objectLoader%3awillMapData%3a)